# How to refresh drop down when click on select using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a drop down in mvc

```
@Html.DropDownList(
  "Name", 
  new SelectList(Model.Product, "Value", "Text"), 
  string.Concat("-- ", "Please select the item", " --"), 
  new { id = "Product", Class = "form-control" }
)
```

I fill dropdown dynamically. It works fine. Everything works fine. When i change the item i perform action that i want using jquery onchange method and refresh the dropdown. But i want to  refresh dropdown when user click on "Please select the item". When i click on please select the onchange method is not called. How i can do this?

```
$DropDown.on("change", function () {


            //Here i perfome action
        });
```

Comment: where is your onchange code?

Comment: i add in question ,check it please

Comment: so everytime you click or change you want to refresh? or just the first time you click, then on every change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to extract the "onchange" function in order to reuse it. Something like that

```
var changeCallback = function(e) {
  // chage logic
}
$("#dropdownlistname").on("change", changeCallback);
$("#dropdownlistname").on("click", changeCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#dropdownlistname').change(function(e){
       // Your event handler
    });

    // And now fire change event when the DOM is ready
    $('#dropdownlistname').trigger('change');
});
```

More Information [Here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

**Edit**

You should provide a selector to the `on` function:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  // Does some stuff 
});
```

In that case, it will work as you expected. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/2jzvuLdn/) using `on` function

Comment: You must declare the change event handler before calling `trigger()` or even `change()` as shown in my answer, that is, if the event handler code appears bellow the call, nothing happens!

Comment: Onchange works fine but when i click on please select, it does not call

Comment: See for any Error in `console` ?

Answer (score 0):

user2052156's answer looks good but if you want the 'click' to happen only the first time then you can remove the click handler after the first call:-

```
$DropDown.on('click change', function(){

    //Here i perfome action

    $(this).off('click');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3c06yf4d/)